# Get rank from a huge unordered score MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table for highscores. This table contains 150,000,000+ entries.

For simplicity, let's assume the structure `highscore (id, userId, itemId score)`. userId and score should be intuitive, I need `itemId` though since the game can be completed with like 100 different items, and I want to find out the ladder ranking for a certain user who used a certain item. (like: user 123456 using item 67 has a score of 1337 and thus is ranked #987654 with that item)

So for example, I have a userId `12345` and want to see how he ranks with itemId `67` in the global ladder list.

On other stackoverflow threads I found solutions like this:

```
SELECT id, userId, itemId, score, rank
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, userId, itemId, score, @n := IF(@g = score, @n, @n + 1) rank, @g := score
    FROM highscore(SELECT @n := 0) i
   ORDER BY score DESC
) q

where userId = 12345 and itemId = 67
```

But this query takes 314 seconds to run (I have mysql indexes for `id`, `score`, `userId, itemId` and `itemId`). I need a solution that allows people to live lookup their global ranking for a run with that item.

Is there any chance to find a query that properly gets me a rank here in reasonable time? (<0.1 seconds) I'm also open-minded for structure and index changes, if needed.

If it's impossible to get this in time, what other ways would there be? Use a cronjob to clone the table every 24 hours, add the row rankByItem and calculate it for each row? Sounds like even more unneccessary work to me.

I hope someone has an idea.

EXPLAIN EXTENDED for the above query (sorry, I don't know how to make tables here. I tried to make it readable):

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  PRIMARY <derived2> ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 215011943 100.00 Using where   |
| 2  DERIVED <derived3> system NULL NULL NULL NULL 1 100.00 Using filesort     |
| 2  DERIVED highscore ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 215033733 100.00                |
| 3  DERIVED NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL No tables used            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `highscore` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `itemId` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `score` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 # ...
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_item` (`userId`,`itemId`),
 KEY `item` (`itemId`),
 KEY `score` (`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=215042396 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Nesting a `SELECT` inside the other generally results in extremely poor optimization and should be avoided. It's actually impressive that a table with 150m entries only takes 314 seconds to do that. You should change your query to not require this structure. If you can't figure out how to do that with one query, there's nothing wrong with doing multiple queries and cross the references yourself.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Also show us the `CREATE TABLE` with indexs.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I added an 'explain extended' above

Comment: use [**SHOW CREATE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html) If you see the sort isnt using the index.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Added show create table

Answer (score 0):

My guess is studying the `EXPLAIN` you can find where the problem is, but lets imagine doesnt, you could solve it follow some `tricks`

In my gaming experience some ranking arent updated in real time because there are time consuming. So you update the rank in time windows.

So if you know the ranking process need 5 minutes. You create a temporal table every 5 minutes

```
CREATE TABLE temp_rank as 
    SELECT id, 
           userId, 
           itemId, 
           score, 
           @n := IF(@g = score, @n, @n + 1) rank, 
           @g := score
    FROM highscore, (SELECT @n := 0, @g := '') i
    ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Then create one index for `userId` and `itemId` in `temp_rank` so all your `SELECT` should be done instanly.

Comment: it should probably be "CREATE TABLE". But even then I get an error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT @n := 0) i
    ORDER BY score DESC' at line 3 `

Comment: Yes, you miss a `,` in the `FROM`

Comment: Thanks! I'll run the query and come back with performance results when it's done.

Comment: The query is still running but there is a huge problem with this method: This query is blocking the table. All attempts to insert or read a score are currently blocked and have to wait for this query to finish. Unfortunatelly this is a no-go for my scenario, since the table is actively used for live score lookups (and inserts, obviously)

Comment: I had to cancel the query. It blocks a very important table for way too much time. Unfortunatelly this can not be the way to go.